# MySQLdb "SELECT FROM" Login

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to log into my table called acounts using MySQLdb in Python, but it does not work for me. I keep getting my message "Not Logged In". Here is my code:

```
database = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pswd", "Kazzah")
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Email='%s' AND Password='%s'" % (_Email, _Password)) 
database.commit()
numrows = cursor.rowcount

if numrows == 1:
    msg = "Logged In"
else:
    msg = "Not Logged In" 

cursor.close()
database.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to this so I hope I've done somewhat good. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing `database.commit()`? You are not writing anything to the DB. Does it work correctly if you remove it? Let me know if it does, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Have you tried running this query in the MySQL interface yourself? What does it return exactly?

Comment: Josvic, I removed it and it does nothing. Linker, yes it works fine in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @MostyMostacho _Email contains the user's email and same for _Password. I've tested it and they do have data.

Comment: It can't result in an error you must be doing something wrong. Additionally, you should make sure the email and password combination are unique

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yes, they are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason (I think because of using Terminal), when I would input the info, I would have to hit Enter. I believe when I would hit enter, the '\n' was inserted and is what caused the numrows to return 0.

I placed

```
.replace('\n', '')
```

After _Email and _Password and now it works great! Now I have one other issue with something else, but nothing big. Thanks to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the quotes from around %s

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Email=%s AND Password=%s" % (_Email, _Password))
```

Comment: with python format strings this could turn into a serious security problem, better use the parameter feature of the database library (see my answer)

Comment: @pjama I needed to add the single quotes cause it gave an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Email=%s AND Password=%s", (_Email, _Password))
```

Try this. If you use MySQLdb's parameter support instead of python's format strings, the library does the escaping for you (which is also a very important point for security reasons.

Note that the mysqldb database driver only supports %s, so you have to use it regardless of the data type you want to send to the database.

Comment: Why isn't numrows returning 1?

Comment: what does it return? 0, None oder something else?

Comment: `print numrows` prints parentheses?

Comment: I finally had a chance to look at the code again and print numrows prints 0.